# Returning 'nil' from a Lua function in C vs returning 0 values

Tags: c, lua

Some Lua functions return `nil` to signal the user that the function couldn't carry out some task (e.g., `tonumber()`, `string.find()`).

In C, returnig `nil` is done like this:

```
int some_function(lua_State* L) {
  ...
  if (some condition) {
      lua_pushnil(L);
      return 1;
  }
  ...
}
```

HOWEVER, I wonder if it's alright to do the following instead:

```
int some_function(lua_State* L) {
  ...
  if (some condition) {
      return 0;
  }
  ...
}
```

It's shorter. I tried it and it seems to works, but I don't know if that's by-design. I examined Lua's source code and I don't see this `return 0` pattern so I wonder if it's legit to do this.

Are the two different ways to return `nil` equivalent?

(BTW, I know all about signaling errors via exceptions (that is, `lua_error()`) so please don't mention it.)

**UPDATE:**

I now see that there's a subtle difference between the two methods: `print((function() end)())` would print nothing whereas `print((function() return nil end)())` would print "nil". I don't know how important this is.

Comment: "I examined Lua's source code and I don't see this return 0 pattern"  How hard did you look? All the Lua library function that don't return a value (e.g. print, table.insert, etc.) return 0 in their C implementation.

Comment: @Mud: The examples you give, `print()` and `table.insert()`, aren't relevant because these functions aren't supposed to return anything. I'm talking about functions that normally *do* return values, like `tonumber()`, and if you inspect their source you'll see that they do `lua_pushnil(L); return 1;`.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Functions in Lua may return `nil` but may also return nothing, and this behavior is not exactly equivalent, although in most context will produce the same results.

The following Lua script shows you how to detect how many return values a function returns:

```
local function PrintNRetVals( ... )
    local nargs = select( '#', ... )
    print( "Number of values returned: " .. nargs )
end

local function ReturningSomething()
    return "hello"
end

local function ReturningNil()
    return nil
end

local function ReturningNothing()
    return
end


PrintNRetVals( ReturningSomething() )   --> 1
PrintNRetVals( ReturningNil() )         --> 1
PrintNRetVals( ReturningNothing() )     --> 0
```

I said the behavior is almost equivalent because as soon as you try to assign to a variable the result of a function that variable will get `nil` in both cases, thus the subsequent code won't be able to tell the difference. But, as I showed above, you can detect the difference if you really need.

Comment: there is a huge difference however if you use `tostring(ReturnNothing())` or `type(ReturnNothing())` it will raise an error however if it is used in a boolean context, lua  will consider it as false.

Comment: @XavierCombelle As I pointed out in my answer, *you can* tell the difference, if you really need. And those two Lua built-in functions do exactly that: they differentiate the two cases (most likely because in that context a missing value, as opposed to a `nil` value, is probably a programming error and not intentional).

Comment: I had a code along these lines `if not ReturnNothing() then print(tostring(ReturnNothing())) end` it took quite a long of debugging time (from my python background) the reason of the following cryptic exception `bad argument #1 to 'tostring' (value expected).` That I want to say is that it is a programming error either in both cases  or in none.

Answer (score 6):

Yes, this is perfectly valid. If you're trying to request/assign more return values than there are (no matter whether you try to get one or ten), you'll get `nil` for the undefined ones (i.e. those not returned).

```
function test1()
    return 5
end

local a, b = test1()
-- a = 5, b = nil

function test2()
    return 1, 2
end

local c, d, e = test2()
-- c = 1, d = 2, e = nil

function test3()
end

local f, g = test3()
-- f = nil, g = nil
```

You probably can't find it in Lua's source because it's no special case or anything. It's just Lua's generic way to handle return values.

Update:

The difference you've noticed when trying to print return values is the fact that this is not just an assignment. Of course there is a slight difference between returning `nil` and returning nothing at all - and it's possible to differentiate there. In the end you'll just have to make sure you document your function's behavior properly, i.e. tell the user what's supposed to happen. For example, returning `nil` (or getting `nil` in an assignment) could represent an error state, but it's also possible to return nothing in case there's been an error and return `nil` if some value is supposed to be invalid or `nil` (but no error happened).

Comment: Thanks. I edited my answer to tell about one subtle difference between returning `nil` vs not returning anything. But I'm a newbie in Lua so I myself can't judge whether this is important or not. I know the reason for this behavior (I'm reading the PiL book). I just wonder why, for example, in the source of 'tonumber()` (in lbaselib.c) they make a point of returning 'nil'.

Comment: For your added update: It's essentially up to interpretation. Of course, there's a difference between returning not a single value and returning one value being `nil`. In an assignment, there won't be any difference, but indeed you can notice a difference depending on how you're using the returned value(s).

Answer (score 2):

This artificial difference between `nil` and `no value` is inconsistent and rather annoying:

```
local function f1() return nil end
local function f0() end

local v1 = f1()     -- OK, assigns nil
print(type(f1()))   -- OK, prints 'nil'

local v0 = f0()     -- OK, assigns nil
print(type(f0()))   -- Why the hack it raises an error?
```

In my opinion, function's parameter passing must fully comply with semantic of assignment statement.

Comment: If you are in danger of getting into such a situation, you can write it like this `print(type((f0())))`. And the error comes from the C function `type`, not from the language. Yes, `type` is in the stdlib, but still the language itself is consistent at least.

Comment: the same behavior appen if you use `tostring`